# Scrap data from multiple categories

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a product at softsurroundings.com

This is the product link: https://www.softsurroundings.com/p/estelle-dress/

```
This product has 3 types of size categories["Misses","Petites","Women"]. Each size category has furthur sizes. i.e. 

for "Misses" we has ["XS","S","M","L","XL"]

for "Petites" we has ["PXS","PS","PM","PL","PXL"]

for "Women" we has ["1X","2X","3X"]
```

I am confused on the css to get the sizes of all three categories.

I get the size of only Misses category because when website loads only Misses category shows
The current code I have is

```
raw_skus = []
    for sku_sel in response.css('.dtlFormBulk.flexItem .size[class="box size"]'):
        sku = {
            'sku_id': sku_sel.css('.size ::attr(id)').get(),
            'size': sku_sel.css('.size ::text').get()
        }
        raw_skus.append(sku)
    return raw_skus
```

the above code returns me

```
[
{'sku_id': 'size_501', 'size': 'XS'}, 
{'sku_id': 'size_601', 'size': 'S'}, 
{'sku_id': 'size_701', 'size': 'M'}, 
{'sku_id': 'size_801', 'size': 'L'}, 
{'sku_id': 'size_901', 'size': 'XL'}
]
```

I am only getting sizes from Misses category I need sizes from other two categories appended in the list too.

Please help.

Comment: It's loaded with JavaScript

Comment: So? Can't it be done?

Comment: You can but you'll need to get it from the [JSON](https://cdn-ws.turnto.com/v5/sitedata/jC1dXvmIBwm2V72site/2FE69/d/review/summary/en_US?).